# Pandas: perform operation on column after aggregating by group

Tags: pandas

If I have the following df, I want to group by column A and divide column D by the max D for each A.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
...:    ...:                           'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
...:    ...:                    'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
...:    ...:                           'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
...:    ...:                    'C' : np.random.randn(8),
...:    ...:                    'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

I tried something like

```
max_by_id = df.groupby('A')['D'].max()
df = df.set_index('A')
df['D'] /= max_by_id.reset_index()['D']
```

but this give me

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: What does not work? I can tel you one thing that doesn't work: `max_by_id` is a series, and `'D'` is not in the index, so `max_by_id['D']` will fail.

Comment: I've updated the code and description :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculated max from the aggregation on the `groupby` object has a reduced index hence the error, if you want to divide the original df column by an aggregation then you can call `transform` on the `groupby` object so that the indices align:

```
In [192]:    
df['D'].div(df.groupby('A')['D'].transform('max'))

Out[192]:
0   -0.601098
1   -0.553823
2   -0.408006
3    1.000000
4    0.312029
5    0.709397
6    1.000000
7    0.140932
Name: D, dtype: float64
```

You can see the difference:

```
In [193]:
df.groupby('A')['D'].transform('max')

Out[193]:
0    1.508660
1    1.378085
2    1.508660
3    1.378085
4    1.508660
5    1.378085
6    1.508660
7    1.508660
Name: D, dtype: float64

In [194]:    
df.groupby('A')['D'].max()

Out[194]:
A
bar    1.378085
foo    1.508660
Name: D, dtype: float64
```

Additionally when you `reset_index` it removes your original `grouped` column labels:

```
In [198]:
max_by_id.reset_index()['D']

Out[198]:
0    0.215997
1    0.962928
Name: D, dtype: float64
```

but before this you set the index to column 'A' but then this will fail:

```
df['D'] /= max_by_id.reset_index()['D']
```

Also you can use a `lambda` with `apply` to do this in the same `lambda`:

```
df.groupby('A')['D'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.max()))
```